# mysql - "Run SQL" command is missing in vs code

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-studio-code

In my `sql` file I noticed the `Run SQL` icon is missing after one of my `insert` statement. I believe the problem is with the `insert from Books` line as the following queries below that are missing the icon as well, but I'm not sure why `insert from Books` would be the problem. Upon running it returns no error, its just the `run SQL` icon is missing.

code:

```
 INSERT INTO customer (ID, Title,Author,Genre,publish) VALUES
 (1, 15, 2, '2015-12-10', '2015-12-17', NULL);

INSERT INTO Books (ID, Title,Author,Genre,publish) VALUES
(1, "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's stone", "J.K. Rowling", "Fantasy", 1997);

 INSERT INTO Patron (ID, Title,Author,Genre,publish) VALUES
 (1, 15, 2, '2015-12-10', '2015-12-17', NULL);
```

Picture of phenomeum:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the single quote in `Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone"` with `''`